# Deleting multiple key value pairs from dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.6

I generated a python dictionary for all the duplicate images in a folder. The python dictonary now contains values in the following format:

```py
{
  "image_1.jpg": ['image_xyz.jpg', 'image_abc.jpg'],
  "image_xyz.jpg": ["image_1.jpg", "image_abc.jpg"],
  "image_abc.jpg": ["image_xyz.jpg","image_1.jpg"],
  "image_2.jpg": ["image_3.jpg"],
  "image_3.jpg": ["image_2.jpg"],
  "image_5.jpg": []
}
```

Each key, value pair thus appears atleast twice in the list. Empty list for keys are present which have no duplicates.
Is there a way to delete all the duplicate key value pairs present? so that the dictionary looks like the following:

```py
{
  "image_1.jpg": ['image_xyz.jpg', 'image_abc.jpg'],
  "image_2.jpg": ["image_3.jpg"],
  "image_5.jpg": []
}
```

I tried using list to first store all the values from the key value pair and then deleting them from the dictionary but it empties the whole dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
source = {
  "image_1.jpg": ['image_xyz.jpg', 'image_abc.jpg'],
  "image_xyz.jpg": ["image_1.jpg", "image_abc.jpg"],
  "image_abc.jpg": ["image_xyz.jpg","image_1.jpg"],
  "image_2.jpg": ["image_3.jpg"],
  "image_3.jpg": ["image_2.jpg"],
  "image_5.jpg": []
}

dest = dict()

for k,v in source.items():
    ok = True
    for k1,v1 in dest.items():
        if k in v1: ok = False
    if ok: dest[k] = v

print(dest) # New filtered dict
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this method when getting rid of duplicates in a list:

First put all the values in a matrix / 2 dimensional list including the key, so the first 3 values would be like this:

```
{
  "image_1.jpg": ['image_xyz.jpg', 'image_abc.jpg'],
  "image_xyz.jpg": ["image_1.jpg", "image_abc.jpg"],
  "image_abc.jpg": ["image_xyz.jpg","image_1.jpg"],
}
```

would turn into:

```
List=[
  ["image_1.jpg","image_xyz.jpg","image_abc.jpg"],
  ["image_xyz.jpg","image_1.jpg","image_abc"],
  ["image_abc.jpg","image_xyz.jpg","image_1.jpg"]
]
```

make sure the keys are all in the 0th position so that you can save them.

```
keys=[x[0] for x in List]
```

then sort the list:

```
sorted_list=[sorted(x) for x in List]
```

then simply compare them using an if statement in a nested for loop and if a list is equal to another then delete it:

```
for i in sorted_list:
    for j,k in enumerate(sorted_list):
        if i==k:
            del sorted_list[j] # deleting any equal lists
```

now that the duplicates are gone and you have the keys convert the list back into a dictionary if preferred

Overall code if needed:

```
List=[
  ["image_1.jpg","image_xyz.jpg","image_abc.jpg"],
  ["image_xyz.jpg","image_1.jpg","image_abc"],
  ["image_abc.jpg","image_xyz.jpg","image_1.jpg"]
]
keys=[x[0] for x in List]
sorted_list=[sorted(x) for x in List]
for i in sorted_list:
    for j,k in enumerate(sorted_list):
        if i==k:
            del sorted_list[j] # deleting any equal lists
```